# PayPal API Reccuring payments

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I need add recurring payments to my site. Before registration user must pay for example 10 GBP for 1 month and thereafter 9 GBP every month.
I try to create recurring payment according to [PayPal][1].
But in IPN i am not recieved responce subscr_signup or other.
When i completed doExpressChechoutPayment i recieved status Pending.
How much time i must wait for authorization is complete? i use sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'=>urlencode('Authorization'),
```

Should be:

```
 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'=>urlencode('Sale'),
```

An authorization will 'hold' the transaction amount (guaranteed by PayPal for up to 3 days, afterwards available for another 26 days), after which you can capture a partial or full amount of the authorized transaction.
In order to immediately capture the funds, set the paymentaction to 'Sale'.
See also [PayPal.com: Using Authorization & Capture](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_authcapture)

Comment: I  excluded doExpressCheckoutPayment API. Then i completed createRecurringProfile, according to this method - http://thereforei.am/2011/07/11/paypal-digital-goods-subscriptions-with-php/. Payment completed successfuly, but i am never recieved in IPN response txn_type=subscr_signup. Maybe you know what?

Comment: Have a look under History > IPN History within the account, and see if the IPN was even generated. If it was, it's your script that's for some reason not receiving it.

Comment: Oh, and ensure your script runs on port 80 or 443. PayPal will not deliver IPN to URL's on any other port beside 80 / 443.

Comment: in IPN History i have all messages, but in txn_type i never seen 'subscr_signup', but i recieved txn_type = recurring_payment_profile_created. Maybe this is equal subscr_signup? When i canceled recurring payment profile, i recieved txn_type = recurring_payment_profile_canceled

Comment: Ah, yes, for recurring payments you'll receive recurring_payment_profile_created. subscr_signup is limited to subscriptions starting with S-. Apologies for missing this earlier.

Comment: How i can set type S or it is not necessarily and i can work with current settings?

Comment: PayPal moved from creating 'subscriptions' (prefixed with S-) to 'recurring payment profiles' (prefixed with I-) back in 2009; all subscriptions and recurring payments (via Express Checkout) created after that time will be the I- type.

Comment: Thank you very much! You realy helped me!)

Comment: one more question: can i set own field to send it to paypal and will recieved it in ipn and nvp responses? for example i need to send user_id, and after response update some fields in db where user_id = my request value

Comment: Yes, `CUSTOM` is available for this.