# paypal API doExpressCheckoutPayment status Pending

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am testing recurring payments. After doExpressCheckoutPayment action i recieved status Pending in my sandbox paypal account. Why status not completed? How much time need to set status Complete? Or maybe need set some params in sandbox. I am used default settings. Payment review - disabled.
Thanks!)
[image]

**UPD 1:**
Here is my request code:

```
public function setPayment($plan){
        $params = array(
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => '10.00',
            'RETURNURL' => $this->base_url.'/paypal/response',
            'CANCELURL' => $this->base_url.'/paypal/paypal',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Authorization',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'GBP',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC' => 'Testing PayPal recurring',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL' => 'http://barton.netai.net/ipn.php',
            'L_BILLINGTYPE0' => 'RecurringPayments',
            'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0' => 'SamePayments'
        );
    $this->_paypal->addFields($params);
    $response = $this->_paypal->request('SetExpressCheckout');
    if (strtoupper($response['ACK'])=='SUCCESS'){
        $token=$response['TOKEN'];
        header('Location: '.$this->_paypal->getPaypalUrl().'?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$token);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function responseAction(){
    if (isset($_GET['token']) && isset($_GET['PayerID'])){
        $this->_paypal->addFields(array('TOKEN'=>$_GET['token']));
        $response=$this->_paypal->request('GetExpressCheckoutDetails');
        if ($response['ACK']=='Success'){
            $response=array();
            $this->_paypal->addFields(array(
                                          'TOKEN' => $_GET['token'],
                                          'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Authorization',
                                          'PAYERID' => $_GET['PayerID'],
                                          'L_BILLINGTYPE0' => 'RecurringPayments',
                                          'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0' => 'SamePayments',
                                          'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => '10.00',
                                          'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'GBP'
                                      ));
            $response=$this->_paypal->request('DoExpressCheckoutPayment');
            show($response); exit;
        }
    }
}
```

SetExpressCheckout response:

```
    Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-01C99915Y11155245
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-02-24T10:23:32Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 69e91a5abc347
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 84
    [BUILD] => 2571254
)
```

doExpressCheckoutPayment response:

```
 Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-2FR88291S31672645
    [SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED] => false
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-02-24T10:26:08Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => a95c7a9bb64b3
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 84
    [BUILD] => 2571254
    [INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED] => false
    [SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT] => false
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID] => 2RN165632T770592L
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME] => 2012-02-24T10:26:06Z
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT] => 10.00
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON] => authorization
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE] => None
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Eligible
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID] => WLC8CZSP2C5L8
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK] => Success
)
```

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409851/paypal-api-reccuring-payments) you advised me to install PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION to Sale,
Maybe this help me to decide this problem?

Comment: Please include the full SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment API request and response. Additionally, what funding source did you choose when completing the transaction?

Comment: i added request and response, see UPD1

Comment: @YuriyNedostup do you get PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL working when you supply it like that? I mean it should only work when supplied in DoExpressCheckoutPayment and ignored in SetExpressCheckout (according to: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/#id1055FM0B05Z__N5060F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the other question, replace;

```
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Authorization',
```

by

```
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
```

Comment: It seems that PayPal api comes with a wrong example for ExpressCheckout

Comment: Not really. Authorization is a perfectly valid value as well if you intend to use Authorization & Capture.

Comment: I meant that Express Checkout Guide from PayPal page 22 makes SetExpressCheckout with 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'  equal to Sale but then bellow use 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' equal to Authorization for DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Comment: @PayPal_Robert can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835944/paypal-sandbox-business-account-not-credited-and-buyer-is-not-debited

Answer (score 0):

When you set the **PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION** to '**Authorization**' , means that you are asking PayPal to check whether the funds are available, and if they are, to place a hold on them for 72 hours. You have up to 29 days to capture an authorization, and when you do, the funds are on hold for three days only. The first 72 hours of the 29-day period are known as the "honor period", meaning that PayPal guarantees that the funds are available.

- The three-day hold occurs in most cases, depending on the
  card-issuing bank, or the bank itself in ACH transactions, such as a
  debit card. In some cases, the three-day hold is waived, whereas in
  other cases there may be a hold on the card for up to 30 days or
  until the next billing cycle.
- If you decide to capture the funds within the last three days of the
  29-day period, those funds are held until the end of the 29th day
  instead of the usual three days.
- You can capture less than the original authorization amount, the full
  amount, or up to 115% of or $75 more than the original authorization,
  whichever is less.

And when you set the **PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION** to '**Sale**' , the payment is processed without holding the funds. The funds are transferred from the buyer's funding source to your PayPal account balance immediately.

- You would use the 'Sale' option for something that is delivered
  quickly, such as digital goods or a product that ships as soon as you
  receive the order.
- The funds are immediately taken from the buyer's funding source and
  sent to your PayPal account balance.